# SAP WEBI - Business Objects Get MIN value when comparing multiple dimensions

Tags: business-objects, webi

How can I get the max or min between 2 different dimensions since there is not an option for multiple values in BOE? My example has 2 dimensions, but I'll need to compare 3. I assume it'll be similar logic for both.

Example:

[image]

```
Syntax

input_type Min(aggregated_data[;member_set])
```

Comment: What is your expected result from the example you have provided?

Comment: To get the min value of the two columns in my example

Comment: Create a minimum variable for each dimesion and then create another variable taking the least of the minimum variables using and IF statement. Depending on how you want to display they data you may have to deal with calculation contexts. What have you tried? Are you getting an error of some sort?